# How do I query related articles based on tags with two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables that I am using in this scenario:  articles, tags, and article_tags.  To manage the tags I use a seperate tags table.  The article_tags table links the articles to the tags.  So the tables look like this:

```
articles:
|-------------------|
|--article_id(int)--|
|-------------------|

tags
|-------------------|
|---tag_id(int)-----|
|--keyword(varchar)-|
|-------------------|

article_tags
|-------------------|
|-article_tag_id(int)|
|-article_id(int)---|
|----tag_id(int)----|
|-------------------|
```

So I want to fetch articles that have the most common tags with the article being viewed and order the results by the matches.  How would I do this?

This is a query that I used when I only used one table for tags.

```
SELECT t2.article_id, count(t2.keyword) AS matches,
                a.article_id AS related_id
            FROM article_tags t1
            JOIN article_tags t2 ON (t1.keyword = t2.keyword AND t1.article_id != t2.article_id)
            JOIN articles a on (t2.article_id = a.article_id)
            WHERE t1.article_id = ".$article_id."
            GROUP BY t2.article_id
            ORDER BY matches DESC
            LIMIT 5
```

Consider [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9991c8) schema... if article id #1 is being viewed both articles 2 and 3 would be included in the results, however, article 3 would be displayed before article 2 because article 2 has more tags in common with the article being viewed(article 1).

Comment: Are you sure this query is correct? article_tags table doesn't have keyword column.

Comment: Providing some sample output would be invaluable for those trying to solve your problem.

Comment: The query I provided is an example that I used before I separated the tags table.  I use the article_tags table to link the tags table to the articles table.   And Tim, I'll get on that.

Comment: What does article_tag_id do? Nothing? Get rid of it.

Comment: It's just the auto increment for the links.  I have also updated the question with a link to an sql fiddle example.

Comment: You really should give a sample output table in your OP.  It's not acceptable have the entire meaning of your question relying on an external SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly your query should look something like this

```
SELECT t2.article_id, COUNT(t2.tag_id) AS matches
FROM (SELECT article_id, tag_id
      FROM article_tags
      WHERE article_id = 1) t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT article_id, tag_id
            FROM article_tags
            WHERE article_id != 1) t2
ON t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
GROUP BY t2.article_id
ORDER BY matches DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

First sub-query t1 select article_id (I think this is not necessary you can only select tag_id) and tag_id for the article is viewed...

Second sub-query t2 select article_id and tag_id for all other article.

Than we do simple INNER JOIN based on tag_id from both sub-query(this will exclude all tag_id from t2 which not match with tag_id from the first table).

After this we just group and order counted tags...

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9991c8/17) to see how it's work.

GL!